# how to Increment optional sub-fields using $inc operator?

Tags: mongodb, increment, exists, mongo-shell, mongodb-update

this are sample documents of the collection,

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId("637f1128d8298d42bae0d4fc"),
    name: 'Iska Paphat',
    age: 8,
    cat: { name: 'Malone Poppelhoffen', age: 7 }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("637f1128d8298d42bae0d4fd"),
    name: 'Elbow Frank',
    age: 67
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("637f1128d8298d42bae0d4fe"),
    name: 'Frank Frank',
    age: 49,
    cat: { name: 'Pirate Yolanda', age: 4 }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("637f1128d8298d42bae0d4ff"),
    name: 'Fluffy Yolanda',
    age: 66
  },
```

I'm trying to increment age and cat.age by 1, using
`db.people.updateMany({},{$inc:{age:1,'cat.age':1}})`,
this command adds`{cats:{age:1}}` in fields which has no cat subfields.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("637f03bcd8298d42bae0d110"),
    name: 'Elbow Pirate',
    age: 5,
    cat: { age: 1 }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("637f03bcd8298d42bae0d111"),
    name: 'Malone Foxton',
    age: 45,
    cat: { age: 1 }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("637f03bcd8298d42bae0d112"),
    name: 'Fluffy Poppelhoffen',
    age: 1,
    cat: { age: 1 }
  },
```

how to $inc both cat's age and person age without adding cat field in **single query**?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) for this. this allows us to incorporate some more complex logic, in this case only increment the age field if the cat exists.

```
db.people.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      age: {
        $sum: [
          "$age",
          1
        ]
      },
      cat: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$cat",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          "$$REMOVE",
          {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$cat",
              {
                age: {
                  $sum: [
                    "$cat.age",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BYTO0r0Mvdb)